# Problem establishing connection to backend that contains websocket server

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, websocket, socket.io, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently hosting my frontend on AWS Cloudfront and using AWS Beanstalk to host my backend server.

I've established a WebSocket server along side my Flask application as shown here

```
from flask import Flask 
from flask_cors import CORS
from parent.extensions import socketio

from parent.extensions import db, migrate
from parent.routes.order import order
from parent.routes.user import user
from parent.routes.ingredient import ingredient_inventory
from parent.routes.transaction import transaction
from parent.routes.payment import payment
from parent.routes.discount import discount_blueprint


from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

# load all environment variables
load_dotenv()



def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)


    CORS(app)

    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.getenv('DATABASE_URI')
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)

    app.register_blueprint(order)
    app.register_blueprint(user)
    app.register_blueprint(ingredient_inventory)
    app.register_blueprint(transaction)
    app.register_blueprint(payment)
    app.register_blueprint(discount_blueprint)

    

    SWAGGER_URL = '/api/docs'  # URL for exposing Swagger UI (without trailing '/')
    API_URL = '/static/swagger.json'  # Our API url (can of course be a local resource)




    socketio.init_app(app)

    
    return app
    
app = create_app()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,port=8080)
```

After which, my Frontend will establish a connection with the WebSocket server as shown here

```
const socket = io.connect(process.env.REACT_APP_SOCKET_URL);
// Environment variable will contain the URL to the backend server
```

But after hosting both on AWS, I realised that there's an error that prevents my frontend from connecting to my backend Flask Application.

[image]

I've been stuck on this for weeks and would greatly appreciate it if there's any kind soul that could help me with this! I'm new to AWS and it might have been some configuration issue on my AWS services that's causing this error.

Thank you!

Comment: Hey do you manage to solve this?